# Secured annotations in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to configure security annotations in spring security. But I have a question about this -

```
....
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
....
```

and when I use

```
@Secured("CUSTOM_ACCESS")
public String query();
```

it doesn't work. But I use

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('CUSTOM_ACCESS')")
public String query();
```

it works correctly and applies relevant Role. Does this mean @Secured annotations doesn't work with @PreAuthorize?

I also tried adding

```
   <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
```

But it doesn't help.

```
   <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
```

The above config works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, the `use-expressions` setting in your `<http>` element has no effect on method security annotations. Those are enabled using `global-method-security`.

Using

```
   <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
```

will enable `PreAuthorize` and its related annotations. The reason the secured annotation isn't working when you enable that is because there is no voter which knows what `CUSTOM_ACCESS` means. In its default setup Spring Security's `RoleVoter` only consumes attributes which start with the prefix `ROLE_`. See [this FAQ](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-role-prefix) for more information.

Voters can be used for things other than checking for simple roles, so they typically need some way of determining which of the attributes configured for a method apply to them. The expression-based annotations operate differently from the standard voters. The `hasRole` expression just looks for a named authority which is assigned to the user.

So if you created an `AccessDecisionManager` for method security, with an `AccessDecisionVoter` which consumes your `CUSTOM_ACCESS` attribute then the `@Secured` annotation would have an effect. However since you have it working with `PostAuthorize` already you may just want to stick with that.

Comment: Can i have both like this.. `<sec:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true"/> `